# Accessing specific elements in a multi-dimensional array of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, indexing

How do I access elements 0-K in a 2D array of pointers with i rows and j columns? 
I was unable to see how using nested for loops to index out the desired element would work, because it is unknown if K is smaller or larger than either i or j.

So, I was thinking that it was necessary to provide for different conditions:

```
if (K < j) {
     //index through the first row
    }

while (K > j) {
     //do some manipulations to determine how many rows to index through 
     }
```

But this just seems unnecessarily complex. Is there a way with using pointers and derefencers to get the value of element K out of a 2D array of pointers?

Say, for example, I want to get the value 7 out of this array:
[image: image.]

(Note: This image does not accurately reflect how a 2D array of pointers looks...I know that is, in essence, an array of 1D arrays.)

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Show an example.

Comment: The Kth-element of a 2-D array would be a 1-D array. Is this what you are after?

Comment: "it is unknown if K is smaller or larger than either i or j." --> If `K` is too big, "access elements 0-K" is **not possible**.

Comment: If you have `int array[10][10];` and you want the `K`th element, you can access it with `array[K / 10][K %10]`, if `K < 100`.

Comment: `for(int r = 0; r < i; ++r){ for(int c = 0; c < j; ++c) { if(r * j + c <= K) access(array[r][c]); } } }`

Comment: @Jessica Ann  Don't give references. Type the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then you need the following.

First of all you can reinterpret a two-dimensional array as a one-dimensional array. And you can split sequential indexes into rows and columns.

In the demonstrative program below there are shown the both approaches.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M   3
#define N   4

int main(void) 
{
    int a[M][N];

    int *p = ( int * )a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M * N; i++ )
    {
        p[i] = i;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M * N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[ i / N ][ i % N ] );
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 ) putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11
```